# Portable real time renderer window without graphical API

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, window, renderer

I am writing a renderer on CPU and GPU (using Cuda) using C++. I do not use DirectX, Vulkan or OpenGL, I am writing the whole rendering pipeline myself as an exercise. For the moment, the result of the rendering is saved as a PNG file.

However, I would like to display the result of the rendering in real time in a window but I do not know how to do it.
For example, in the Nvidia OptiX examples (https://github.com/nvpro-samples/optix_advanced_samples), they create a window using glfw3 and then they create an OpenGL context and they display the result of the OptiX rendering on a simple texture inside the OpenGL context. I would like to do the same, but I do not want to create an OpenGL context because I want to have a portable solution (Windows and Linux) which do not use any graphical API. I do not want to rely on OpenGL, especially if it is only for the display.

Is there a portable C++ library for managing a window and displaying in real time a texture without using any major graphical API (DirectX, Vulkan, OpenGL) ?

Edit: Thank you for your answers. I was probably not so clear in my initial question. I want to use a GUI but I do not want to use a hardware accelerated API such as OpenGL. Because 60 times per second I refresh a buffer in memory which contains the rendering of my scene (an array of 8 bits unsigned int, with a simple RGB representation, 3 values per pixel), and I just want to display this buffer inside a window 60 times per second.

Comment: Think of your rendered image as a bitmap.  How would you display a bitmap?  At some point you'll need to call OS specific functions to do t.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to display a rendered png in real-time (well it depends what you define real-time as ^^) with only WinAPI/Xlib.

Comment: Asking for libraries is considered off-topic here. That said, I recommend SDL2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are standalone libraries like [Window-API](https://github.com/ziacko/Window-API) that will provide cross-platform window management (Linux + Windows, in that case).

There are frameworks like [Qt](https://www.qt.io) and [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org) that do that and much more, like providing you a kitchen sink, refrigerator, backyard rocket launching pad, etc.

You're still going to need to talk to a "graphical" API or framework of some sort (hence GUI, graphical user interface) but you can certainly display images, animations, videos, etc, outside of *hardware-accelerated 3D* graphical rendering contexts like OpenGL, Vulkan, or DirectX.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was probably not so clear in my question. I want to use a GUI but I do not want to use a hardware accelerated API such as OpenGL. Because 60 times per second I refresh a buffer in memory which contains the rendering of my scene, and I just want to display this buffer inside a window.

Comment: The first two paragraphs addressed that. The third paragraph was saying yes, it's possible to do this basic kind of display outside of OpenGL/DirectX/Vulkan. Actually there are a hundred ways to do what you ask, not just one or two -- pick your library of choice and go! GTK, GDI, MFC, SDL, all of them can do basic windowing, and regardless of OS, that window is the "thing" upon which you'll paint your rendered output.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, just use User32 and GDI. (or other DLLs like gdiplus.)

For Linux distros, you can use GTK or KDE.

Also, there are cross-platform libraries like SDL.

These libraries support high(?)-level windowing apis. Thus you can get canvas (or surface) of widget (or window) and you can simply copy your rendering result. Just copy bitmap.

Or, you can use directly low-level graphics infra libraries like EGL to get display surface.